# Using Terraform import to import IAM users on IBM Cloud

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm, terraform-import

I'm trying to import IBM Cloud users, previously created with terraform, into a new state file after the old one was accidentally deleted!

In our tf file we have the resource:

```
resource "ibm_iam_user_invite" "account_users" {
  users = var.account_users
}
```

In our variables.tf file we have the variable:

```
variable "account_users" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of all the current users with access to the IBM Cloud account"
}
```

And in our terraform.tfvars we have:

```
account_users = [
"user1@domain.com",
"user2@domain.com",
"user3@domain.com",
...
...
]
```

I can import a single user successfully using this command:

```
terraform import 'ibm_iam_user_invite.account_users' user1@domain.com
```

But when I try and import more users I get an error saying

> Error: Resource already managed by Terraform
>
> Terraform is already managing a remote object for
> ibm_iam_user_invite.account_users. To import to this address you must first
> remove the existing object from the state.

How do I correctly import the users?

Comment: According to the documentation "The import functionality is not supported for this resource." so that would be both an answer and non-answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The single invitation works because you assigned the name "account_users" to `user1@domain.com`. The, you tried to invite another user to the same TF resource name. Try `'ibm_iam_user_invite.account_users2'` and it should work.

The resource allows to manage multiple users in a list. It seems that feature is not supported for import.